# DRY out snippet of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dry

Can the following be DRYed up a little?

```
if(totals[label]) {
    totals[label] += increment;
} else {
    totals[label] = increment;
}
```

Basically, I have a special case when `totals[label] === undefined`, because `undefined + increment === NaN` whenever `typeof increment === 'number'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's totally fine, you didn't repeat too much. Yes, you could use

```
totals[label] = (totals[label] || 0) + increment;
```

but imho that doesn't save much. I think

```
if (label in totals)
    totals[label] += increment;
else
    totals[label] = increment;
```

is easier to read since it better expresses what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
totals[label] = (totals[label] || 0) + increment;
```